# Этимология слова подушка

Tags: этимология

Как случилось, что такое милое изобретение - подушка имеет общий корень с глаголом душить?

Comment: Позвольте ответить вам вашим вопросом, а с,чего вы взяли, что глагол *душить* имеет негативный смысл? Если взять духи то ими тоже можно душиться. САШЕ из ароматных трав заправленных в ткань подушка.

Comment: Я понимаю, что на эту мысль вас навёл эпитет "милое", но он относится к слову "изобретение" , а глаголу "душить" в своём вопросе я не давал никаких определений.

Answer (score 2):

Общепризнанной этимологии у слова "подушка" нет.

Можно действительно предположить, что слово связано со значением "воздушный", "надутый" и таким образом восходит к общеславянскому морфу "дух" с широким спектром значений, куда входит и "душить".

Совершенно необоснованно утверждение, что "подушка это то, что под ухом". Такое объяснение является ничем иным, как только народной этимологией.

Comment: А каково здесь значение предлога ПО, если  считать, что подушка - это нечто надутое (народная этимология как раз связана с предлогом ПОД, который мог перейти в предлог ПО).  И что можно сказать о словах "подуха", а также "додуха", они связаны с подушкой?

Comment: @Sharon  это не предлог, это приставка. И приставка, скорее всего, глагольная - "подышать". Про два те слова ничего не могу сказать. Возможно вторичное переосмысление.

Comment: Спасибо, приставка, конечно. Но она-то и занимает мое воображение.

Answer (score 1):

Большой этимологический словарь (2011 год, составитель Климова М.В.)

**ПОДУШКА**. Возникновение: X — XI вв., от общеславянского исчезнувшего **"подуха": буквально "надутое"**.

Этимология слова действительно неясная. В словаре Черных его нет, у Фасмера приводятся только гипотезы, **и подушка как нечто надутое — это тоже гипотеза,** только наиболее распространенная.

**Фасмер:** подушка поду́шка укр. по́душка, по́духа, др.-русск. подушька, др.-чеш. роduсhа (Ягич, Ksl.-böhm. Glossen 29), чеш., слвц. роduškа, польск. poduszka. Слав. *ро-dušьkа связано с сербохорв. духња "перина", чеш. duchna, польск. duchna, **далее – с дух, т. е. "надутое", по мнению Бернекера (1, 235), Брюкнера (426), Голуба–Копечного (283), Ильинского (ИОРЯС 20, 3, 81).** Другие пытаются произвести от под и у́хо (Махек, LF 55, 147), против чего Брандт (РФВ 25, 33). Неудачна гипотеза о тюрк. происхождении (ср. тюфя́к) у Когена 1, ИОРЯС 23, 1, 31. •• 1 У Когена (см. там же) сказано: "Можно ... видеть заимствование из турецкого или татарского, ср. сербск. ду̀шек "матрац".

Поэтому попробую высказать **свое личное мнение.**

**1) Почему мне не нравится версия "надутое"**

Подушку не надували воздухом, а набивали чем-то мягким. В древности это вообще были деревянные дощечки. "В Японии подушки из дерева, металла, камня или фарфора использовались повсеместно до 19 века". Первые мягкие изделия появились в Древней Греции.
Так неужели в основу названия было положено **метафорическое сравнение "как будто надутое."**

**2) Словообразование**

Непонятно значение приставки ПО, вряд ли она принадлежала глаголу ***подышать***. (Мы же не считаем, что существительные *повар* и *поход* образовались от глаголов *походить* и *поварить*). Здесь способ образования скорее префиксально-суффиксальный, например: дышать — по/дух/а — по/душ/к/а.

**3) Значение**

Каким-то образом подушка связана с функцией дыхания у человека. Это или ее расположение, или  предназначение (обеспечение удобства дыхания, как вариант).

4) **Версия с приставкой ПОД** тоже возможна, сравнить подушка — подголовье (у Даля). По крайней мере, значения этих двух приставок могли сближаться. (Это, конечно, отнюдь не означает, что подушку клали под ухо).

Еще раз хочу сказать, что это только мои собственные мысли, в которых выражено **недоверие** к гипотезе "надутое".

Answer (score 1):

Ст. слав. подуха и позже подушка не имеет отношения к душе или дуть, но очень логично и просто "под ухом". Люди в основном спят "на ухе". В сербском называется и подглавник, подглавец и следует той же логике.

Comment: Отмечу в комментарии, что А.К. Шапошников в своём этимологическом словаре также считает такое толкование более правильным.

Answer (score -3):

Мое личное мнение, у каждого думающего человека ведь есть такое право? . Подушка и Подиум имеют общие корни ,восходящие к каменному алтарю в котором было углубление ямка в которую приносили дары .Была ли это жертвенная кровь или тлели благовония у разных народов и цивилизаций на то были свои взгляды.
ps Особо ценные ювелирные украшения ,ордена  в особенно торжественные моменты выкладывают куда бы вы думали ?

Comment: Спасибо, Себастьян, за ответ! Пробежался тут по словарям(озадаченный вашими параллелями), связи между "подушка" и "подиум" не обнаружил. Вы уж извините...

Comment: Читающий да увидит . Подушка Подиум Жервенный алтарь .Прародителем слов подушка ,подиум был алтарь ,камень с лункой,ямкой .

Comment: Не пускают комментировать бегемотуса ,глагольная приставка ,По ,какая мерзость . Подышать . По если и глагольная то связана она не с воздухом, а,а водой ,слезами,впитывать как губка ,оставаясь сухой  .логопеды.

Comment: Вы считаете, что  общеславянское слово заимствовано из латинского (или греческого) языка? Но это же надо как-то доказать.   Есть такая информация: ПОДИУМ. Происходит от латинского podium «постамент, подиум», далее из древнегреческого πόδιον «ножка», уменьш. от πούς (род. п. ποδός) «нога», далее из праиндоевропейского *ped- «нога». Получается, что слово заимствовано со значением "выступ, возвышение"? Кстати,   подушка у римлян  - это pulvinus (лат.).

Comment: Разговор по кругу ,pulvinus ,опять всплывает Саше  ароматная трава ,pulvinus (ботаника) .Мы ходим по кругу...